# Calculation of age and age ranges from DOB

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (called baseline) with a column of dates of birth (DOB) in the format mm/dd/yyyy. I want to calculate age as of 'today' based on DOB and put the ages into a new column called Age. I also want to calculate age ranges (18 - 35, 36 - 44) and put that into another column called Age Range. (It could even be 0 for 18-35 and 1 for 36 - 44).

This is how I tried calculating Age:

```
baseline$Age <- age_calc(as.Date(baseline$DOB, "%m/%d/%Y"), enddate=Sys.Date(), 
                         units="years", precise=TRUE)
```

but I got this error:

```
Error in mapply(seq, as.POSIXct(start), as.POSIXct(end), by = "years",  : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
```

I haven't attempted to calculate the age ranges - I don't really know where to start with that one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a package issue, but you won't need any.

You appear to have data like this:

```
head(dat, 3)
#          DOB something
# 1 02/21/1993 0.6756073
# 2 03/01/1924 0.9828172
# 3 10/31/1945 0.7595443
```

First, define `"today"`

```
today <- as.Date('2022-01-01')  ## hardcoded
# today <- Sys.Date()  ## alternatively dynamic
```

Then, using `within`, successively define variables like so.

```
dat <- within(dat, {
  DOB <- as.Date(DOB, "%m/%d/%Y")  ## coerce to `"Date"` class
  age <- as.numeric(today - DOB)/365.25  ## calculate years
  age_cat <- cut(age, c(0, 17, 35, 44, Inf),  ## cut in categories
                 c('<18', '18-35', '36-44', '>44'))
  age2 <- round(age)  ## maybe
})

dat
#           DOB something age2 age_cat        age
# 1  1993-02-21 0.6756073   29   18-35  28.859685
# 2  1924-03-01 0.9828172   98     >44  97.837098
# 3  1945-10-31 0.7595443   76     >44  76.169747
# 4  1921-01-30 0.5664884  101     >44 100.919918
# 5  2000-07-16 0.8496897   21   18-35  21.462012
# 6  1924-11-21 0.1894739   97     >44  97.111567
# 7  1992-04-07 0.2712866   30   18-35  29.735797
# 8  1937-04-06 0.8281585   85     >44  84.739220
# 9  2009-10-09 0.6932048   12     <18  12.229979
# 10 1978-03-11 0.2405447   44   36-44  43.811088
# 11 2014-10-31 0.0429888    7     <18   7.170431
# 12 2011-01-15 0.1404791   11     <18  10.962355
# 13 1962-03-21 0.2163854   60     >44  59.783710
# 14 1930-09-24 0.4793986   91     >44  91.271732
# 15 1992-04-20 0.1974103   30   18-35  29.700205
```

Here in detail what `cut()` does:

```
setNames(cut(16:46, c(0, 17, 35, 44, Inf), c('<18', '18-35', '36-44', '>44')), 16:46)
#    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26 
#   <18   <18 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 
#    27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37 
# 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 18-35 36-44 36-44 
#    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45    46 
# 36-44 36-44 36-44 36-44 36-44 36-44 36-44   >44   >44
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(DOB=strftime(sample(seq.Date(as.Date('1900-01-01'), 
                                               as.Date('2022-01-01'), 'day'), 15),
                               "%m/%d/%Y"),
                  something=runif(15))
```